# KeyPress event using textbox C# winform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, keypress

I have lot of textbox in my winform. maybe 20 to 30 textbox.
and I need all texbox have numerical only when typing.

I use keypress event per textbox to handle the numerical only(code below)

```
 if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            // only allow one decimal point
            if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

is there possible way to inherit all textboxes in just 1 keypress event?

Comment: You alreay have the event, just assign it to all textboxes' 'keypress' event.

Comment: In VS, select all textboxes, then in property inspector, go to events and select your eventhandler.

Comment: @PoulBak I already did it all textbox had keypress event. I'm asking if there's possible way for simple coding not apply keypress event to all textbox.

Comment: Do you create the textboxes dynamically?

Comment: Curious - what is the following line actually doing (ie the control stuff)...


```
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.')) 
```

I use the following -does it fail in some circumstances? ...


```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the keypress event for only one textbox.

Then select another text box and go to keypress event and select the method you already implemented.

[image]